# Where do I fix partial words incorrectly identified as errors with spell?

Tags: spell-checking

I upgraded MacVim to 8.1.2168 (159) tonight and now the vimwiki files in Markdown format do not highlight correctly when I enable spell check.

I run `set spell spelllang=en_ca` as I have before. It looks almost like the spell check is finding all of the first word *except the first character* in some (but not all!) of the sentences, and reporting those fractions of words as misspellings.

[image: incorrect spell error hightlight]

I believe this is some sort of new conflict between the vimwiki files in Markdown format and the new upgraded version of vim and [spellcapcheck](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'spellcapcheck')

Abridged output from `set:`

```
 syntax=vimwiki      
 filetype=vimwiki    
 spell  
 spellcapcheck=[.?!]_[])'
 spellfile=~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
 suffixesadd=.markd
```

I can see that the default string for [spellcapcheck](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'spellcapcheck') is `default "[.?!]\_[\])'"' \t]\+"`  while mine is `[.?!]_[])'`.  Yet I run

```
set spc="[.?!]\_[\])'"' \t]\+"
```

and the highlighting does not change.

When I run `set list` I can see that there is an eol at the end of each line.  This is as I expect.

It is not lost on me that the first word of each sentence is *not* highlighted if the remaining characters after the first character form a valid word:

- **David** does *not* appear as a highlighted spelling error because `avid` is a valid word.
- **Daphne** appears as a highlighted spelling error because `aphne` is a typo.

Where do I look next to fix this?

---

Comment: I honestly cannot reproduce this with `spelllang=en_ca` and `spellcapcheck=[.?!]_[])'` on terminal vim 8.1.1850. Is it only vimwiki files that do this?

Comment: The command you used to try to reset `'spellcapcheck'` to its default isn't correct (See `:help option-backslash` and note that you *shouldn't* be including the surrounding quotes that are mentioned in the documentation for `:help 'spc'`.) Having said that, I can't reproduce your issue either. Does running `:set spc&` affect the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5078), introduced by patch [v8.1.2153](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2153) that has since been fixed with patch [v8.1.2172](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/7751d1d1a3d447d0d48f57f34e0da9f7c6ac433d), so you'd need to update your MacVim to a new Version.

Comment: I confirm that the problem is no longer present after I updated MacVim to 8.1.2224. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. Just upgraded to `8.1.2168` a couple days ago. A couple things I noticed:

- My default `spellcapcheck` was set to `[.?!]\_[\])'"^I ]\+`, changing it to yours (`[.?!]_[])'`) or `[.?!]\_[\])'"' \t]\+` had no effect.
- Perhaps more interestingly, it doesn't appear that these are actually recognized as typos: when I use `]s` and `[s` to move to misspelled words, vim skips over the words at the start of lines (unless they are explicitly misspelled).

In other words, looks like gvim doesn't actually *think* these are misspelled words, but erroneously highlights them anyways.

I tested this by opening up an empty file (`vim -u NONE`), running `set spell`, typing some words (some purposefully misspelled), observing what was highlighted, and using `]s` & `[s` to see what was actually flagged as misspelled.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is fascinatingly useful information for the question, but doesn't really *answer* it. It might be better as a comment on the question, or an edit to add more information.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I 100% agree. Unfortunately, since I am a new member, I am actually unable to add comments until I have a reputation of 15. I wanted to add a comment initially because I did not have a direct answer :( (Edit: Actually I need a reputation of 50 to post comments on other people's questions/answers)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble also thank you for the information. What would you recommend to be the correct course of action in this situation? I'd like to follow the rules and recommendations diligently.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. You could put up a custom flag for a moderator to ask, or ask on [meta]

Comment: Thanks for your help!